# Proving $\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left({\prod\limits_{k=0}^n( n+k)}\right)^{1/n}=\frac{4}{e}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Prove that: $$\underset{n\ \rightarrow +\infty }{\overset{}{\lim }} \ \frac{\sqrt[n]{\prod\limits ^{n}_{k=0}( n+k)}}{n} =\frac{4}{e}$$

I think to apply Stolz-Cesaro but I don't know if it works.

Comment: Well, what would $$\frac{a_{n+1} - a_n}{b_{n +1}-b_n}$$ look like and what is it's limit for $n \to \infty$?

Comment: In numerator I have a difference of radiacal maybe I must use $ln$ to transfom the radicals ?

Comment: @asv the simplest solution the application of Stirling approximation $n!\approx \sqrt{2\pi n}\frac{n^n}{e^n}$

Comment: It is an exercise on first chapters of calculus textbook. I think it is possible to solve without Stirling. However thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**METHODOLOGY $1$**

Without appeal to either Stirling's Formula or Cesaro-Stolz  we can write

$$\begin{align}
\left(\prod_{k=0}^n (n+k)\right)^{1/n}&=e^{\log(n)+\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^n\log\left(1+\frac kn\right)+\frac{\log(n)}{n}}\\\\
&=n^{1+1/n}e^{\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^n \log\left(1+\frac kn\right)}
\end{align}$$

Dividing by $n$, recognizing that $\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^n \log\left(1+\frac kn\right)$ is the Riemann sum for $\int_0^1 \log(1+x)\,dx=\log(4/e)$, and letting $n\to\infty$ reveal

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(\prod_{k=0}^n (n+k)\right)^{1/n}}{n}=\frac4e$$

as was to be shown!

---

**METHODOLOGY $2$**

If we are not equipped with knowledge of Riemann Sums, then we can proceed by applying the Cesaro-Stolz Theorem to evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^n\log\left(1+\frac kn\right)$.  Proceeding we find

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^n\log\left(1+\frac kn\right)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\log\left(1+\frac k{n+1}\right) -\sum_{k=0}^n\log\left(1+\frac kn\right)\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\log\left(2\right) +\sum_{k=0}^n\log\left(\underbrace{\frac{k+n+1}{k+n}}_{\text{Telescope}}\frac{n}{n+1}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\log(2)+\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\log(2n+1)-\log(n)\right)\\\\
&=\log(4/e)
\end{align}$$

whence we find

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(\prod_{k=0}^n (n+k)\right)^{1/n}}{n}=\frac4e$$

as expected!

Comment: Thank you, this exercise is on first chapters of calculus textbook then I guess it should be possible to solve it without integral.

Answer (score 2):

This is based on the logarithmic version of Cesaro-Stolz. By Cesaro-Stolz we have $$a_{n+1}-a_n\to L\implies \frac{a_n} {n} \to L$$ Putting $a_n=\log x_n, x_n>0$ we get the desired logarithmic version $$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\to L\implies \sqrt[n] {x_n} \to L$$ For current question let $$x_n=\frac{1}{n^n}\prod_{k=0}^{n}(n+k)$$ so that $$\frac {x_{n+1}}{x_n}=\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n}\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{n(n+1)}$$ which tends to $4/e$. Thus the desired limit $\sqrt[n] {x_n} \to 4/e$.

Comment: Thank you very much